# How to get IonQ Task's Native Instructions/Decomposition (Amazon Braket)

Tags: compiling, amazon-braket, ionq

When you run something on one of IBM's free computers, you can look up what it actually ran; i.e. it gives you the decomposition of the circuit you told it to run.

When running on IonQ with Amazon's braket I can't find that. I can call up the task data like this:

```
task_data = AwsQuantumTask(arn='generic_task_ID_string')
print(task_data.result().additional_metadata.action.instructions)
```

Apparently if I ran it on a Rigetti device I could do something like:

```
task_data = AwsQuantumTask(arn='generic_task_ID_string')
print(task_data.result().additional_metadata.rigettiMetadata.compiledProgram)
```

but I see no such `ionQMetadata` thing for IonQ. Does anyone know if such a thing can be obtained? I've worked out viable native-gate decompositions for what *might* have actually run for my circuit but I need to make sure I've got what actually ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Braket documentation:

**Verbatim compilation is currently supported on Rigetti and Oxford Quantum Circuits (OQC) devices and requires the use of native gates.**

In other words, Braket does not allow machine-level control over an IonQ device nor are you allowed to see what commands it actually ran.

Source: Page 43 from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/braket/latest/developerguide/braket-developer-guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Update: The IonQ gate decomposition is not available, but Amazon Braket now supports native programming on the IonQ device ([see cell 23](https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-examples/blob/main/examples/braket_features/Verbatim_Compilation.ipynb)). The new version of the SDK, 1.30.0, adds [three native gates](https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-sdk-python/blob/main/src/braket/circuits/gates.py#L1902-L2094).

You can programmatically see the supported gates through the device's `properties`:

```
>>> from braket.aws import AwsDevice
>>> ionq = AwsDevice("arn:aws:braket:::device/qpu/ionq/ionQdevice")
>>> ionq.properties.paradigm.nativeGateSet
```

```
['GPI', 'GPI2', 'MS']
```